# R function: removing objects from workspace

Tags: r, function

In my function, I need to store some objects in the workspace using e.g.

```
matrix <<- mean(matrix)
```

as I am referring to that object in other functions nested within the "global function". However, I would like to delete these objects at the end of the "global function". How can this be achieved? `rm()` does not work...

UPDATE:

I outsourced the plotting part of my function and am sourcing this within the "higher order function".

The plotting function sort of looks like this

```
plot_minaverage <- function(minaverage){
  for_minaverage_plot.time <- rep(seq(1,1440),2)
  seq <- seq(start.time*60, length.out = 1440)
  minaverage_plot_time <- for_minaverage_plot.time[seq]

  minaverage_plot_df <- data.frame (minaverage_plot_time, minaverage)

  pp <- ggplot(minaverage_plot_df, aes(x=minaverage_plot_time, y = minaverage))+ 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
theme_bw()+
print(pp)
}
```

The problem I have is that minverage is computed in the "higher order" function and when I do not store it in workspace as mentioned above, the plotting function cannot access it.

Thanks so much for your thoughts on this!

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to use `<<-`. Could you show us more of your code so that we can suggest some better solution?

Comment: Maybe, you should specify the global environment for this: `rm(matrix, envir = globalenv())`.

Comment: If only nested functions use this object you don't need to store it in the global environment. You can store it in the most outer function's environment.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I described the problem in more detail now.